# jQuery animate() and css() not performing well in firefox and internet explorer

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, css, animation

I am making a webapp that needs a division to expand on click. (The division is loaded with content, so it was likely to not animate very well, but I increased the animation time to 1s to make it look smooth) I assigned an event on it and it works absolutely fine in chrome, without hitch or flicker, but in firefox and internet explorer, these issues are there. Here is my JS function to implement this:

```
$activeId = '';
$hider = function($ID) {
    if ($activeId.length) {
        $shower($activeId)
    };
    $activeId = $ID;
    $('#' + $ID).css('opacity', '0');
    $('#' + $ID).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('#' + $ID + '-main-div').animate({
        height: '900px'
    }, 1000);
    $('#' + $ID + "-btn").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('#' + $ID + "-floating-closer").addClass('animate')
};
$shower = function($ID) {
    $('#' + $ID).css('opacity', '1');
    $('#' + $ID).css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('#' + $ID + '-main-div').animate({
        height: '260px'
    }, 800);
    $('#' + $ID + "-btn").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('#' + $ID + "-floating-closer").removeClass('animate');
    $activeId = ''
};
```

The division that expands has these CSS properties:

```
.row-container{
  height: 260px;
}
```

After performing manual removal of elements, I have noticed that the animation affecting the overall performance is this:

```
$('#' + $ID + '-main-div').animate({
        height: '900px'
    }, 1000);
```

Kindly note that the code works absolutely fine on Chrome, it also works on Firefox and IE as well, but with very low performance. Is there a better practice to make to the animation smoother on Firefox and IE as well?

**Update:** The code snippet has been posted. Kindly go through it please. Also, notice that adding the **animation square-animation to the .row-container in CSS makes the animation smooth in Firefox.** I read that it forces hardware acceleration for animating CSS. The performance issue persists in IE.

```js
$activeId = '';
$hider = function($ID) {
    if ($activeId.length) {
        $shower($activeId)
    };
    $activeId = $ID;
    $('#' + $ID).css('opacity', '0');
    $('#' + $ID).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('#' + $ID + '-main-div').animate({
        height: '850px'
    }, 1000);
    $('#' + $ID + "-btn").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('#' + $ID + "-floating-closer").addClass('animate')
};
$shower = function($ID) {
    $('#' + $ID).css('opacity', '1');
    $('#' + $ID).css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('#' + $ID + '-main-div').animate({
        height: '260px'
    }, 800);
    $('#' + $ID + "-btn").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('#' + $ID + "-floating-closer").removeClass('animate');
    $activeId = ''
};
```

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .row-container{
    height: 260px;
    /* animation: square-animation 5s infinite; */
  }
  
 
  @keyframes square-animation {
    0%, 100% {
      transform: rotate(0.01deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(0.01deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0.01deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(0.01deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(0.01deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(0.01deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0.01deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0.01deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0.01deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0.01deg);
    }
  }
  
  .cat-child{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    z-index: 100;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.9));
    vertical-align: middle;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: all 1s;
  }
  
  .cat-button{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 90;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  
  .floating-closer{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 90;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #FFF;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1rem;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    height: 56px;
    width: 56px;
    right: 15px;
    top: 15px;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all 0.4s;
  }
  
  .floating-closer.animate{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  
  .sub-cat-tags{
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 7.5px;
    padding-right: 7.5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    background: #00F;;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  
  .navbar-toggler{
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 8px;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8;">
    <meta name="author" content="Test">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scalable=0">
    <title>
        Test | Home
    </title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script async src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("window").ready(function () {
            $('li.active').removeClass('active');
            $('.home').addClass('active');
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="sticky-top">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-toggleable-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-lg-0 dual-collapse2">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item home">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="mx-auto order-0">
                <a class="navbar-brand d-flex mx-auto" href="/">Test</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-lg-3 order-3 dual-collapse2">
            </div>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid text-white">
        <div class="row row-container" id="Test-main-div">
            <div class="col-12 h-100" style="overflow: hidden;">
   
                <button class="btn floating-closer" id="Test-floating-closer" onclick="$shower('Test')">
                    <span>X</span>
                </button>
                <div class="row cat-child h-100 align-items-center m-0" id="Test" onclick="$hider('Test')">
                    <div class="text-center col">
                        <h1 class="display-1">Test</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h1 class="text-dark font-weight-bold">Divisions (content heavy) that are sitting behind.</h1>
                <div class="row cat-button">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <a href="/test">
                            <button id="test-btn" class="btn font-weight-bold btn-light m-0 h-100 w-100" style="visibility: hidden;">
                                <h5>Test</h5>
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-container" id="Test2-main-div">
            <div class="col-12 h-100" style="overflow: hidden;">
                <button class="btn floating-closer" id="Test2-floating-closer" onclick="$shower('Test2')">
                    <img src="/img/cross.svg" height="22px" width="22px" />
                </button>
                <div class="row cat-child h-100 align-items-center m-0" id="Test2" onclick="$hider('Test2')">
                    <div class="text-center col">
                        <h1 class="display-1">Test2</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <h1 class="text-dark font-weight-bold">Divisions (content heavy) that are sitting behind.</h1>
                <div class="row cat-button">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <a href="/test2">
                            <button id="test2-btn" class="btn font-weight-bold btn-light m-0 h-100 w-100" style="visibility: hidden;">
                                <h5>Test2</h5>
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

<script>$(function () { $(document).click(function (event) { $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide'); }); });</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to ask this question at stackOverflow  https://stackoverflow.com. This is code review and we don't fix code problems.

Comment: Hi @Blindman67 As I mentioned, the webapp performs flawlessly on Chrome. It also implements the functionality in firefox, but the performance of animation is ridiculous. That is why I posted it here; to get suggestions on how to boost the performance.

Comment: I suggest that you make a live demo by pressing Ctrl-M in the question editor.

Comment: For the close-voters: It appears to be a performance issue, not actual broken code, so voting to not close

Comment: @200_success The live demo has been updated. Thanks for help! :)

Comment: @Dannnno Thanks a lot! I have also added the live demo to the question, kindly suggest any performance improvement that can be done to the code. Again, thanks!

Comment: Worth trying: avoid simultaneous css animation and jQuery animation. Shouldn't matter but maybe does here due to (a) heavy content and (b) the css-animated element being within the jQuery-animated element.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I dug google to solve the problem. The only apparent solution is to not modify CSSOM a lot after the page is rendered completely. It looks like that it results in re-rendering of the whole CCSOM, and thus, results in jittering while animating. The best practice here would be to use the transforms and not explicitly modifying the element's dimensions (Which forces Hardware Acceleration and results in smoothing of the animations). I went for a different approach for my webapp, and hence I am not in need to get answer to this question.

Comment: However, since this is a fairly big problem, the obvious solution is to use transforms rather than modifying element dimensions. 

Refer to this page: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/performant-expand-and-collapse

Comment: What makes you think the CSSOM gets modified? Your javascript performs jQuery methods `.css()`, `.animate()`, `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`, all of which operate on the DOM, not the CSSOM.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 That's correct. I didn't check the documentation properly. Also, I made the div empty and ran one animation at one time, still jittering is there if dimensions are modified explicitly. Also, I found the probably cause to this, pl refer to this: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/avoid-large-complex-layouts-and-layout-thrashing

Comment: Sorry I can't be more heplful.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 It's fine. I was already forced to leave design. Thanks a lot for all the help. :D